# Uncaught exception handler not called

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, exception, foundation

I'm trying to catch exceptions on my Mac app so that I can log them in a custom log file. I'm implementing the exception handler like this:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"It Works!");
}
```

And I'm setting it in my `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method like this:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Then I cause an exception to test it like this:

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"object"] objectAtIndex:1];
```

The exception gets logged to the console, but my exception handler is not being called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use the `ExceptionHandling` framework. Here's how I did it:

In `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
[[NSExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler] setExceptionHandlingMask:NSLogAndHandleEveryExceptionMask];
[[NSExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler] setDelegate:self];
```

Then in my App Delegate class I implement to two delegate methods,

```
- (BOOL)exceptionHandler:(NSExceptionHandler *)sender shouldLogException:(NSException *)exception mask:(NSUInteger)aMask
- (BOOL)exceptionHandler:(NSExceptionHandler *)sender shouldHandleException:(NSException *)exception mask:(NSUInteger)aMask
```

Now I can catch all exceptions!

Answer (score 3):

AppKit has its own high-level exception handler on the main thread that is catching the exception first.  You can subclass `NSApplication` and override `-reportException:` to get a chance to do something with it.

Your exception handler may still get called on other threads, though.

Reference: [Tim Wood's message on macosx-dev back in 1999](http://markmail.org/message/6n5rup5xiut775s4).

Comment: I tried that and I'm still not catching the exception. `-reportException:` never gets called. If the exception was raised in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, shouldn't it be called? Isn't that run on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is called on the main thread. Are you sure your `NSApplication` subclass is being used? You need to specify its class name in your `Info.plist` under the key `NSPrincipalClass`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. `[NSApp class];` returns my subclass.

Comment: I've also tried using ExceptionHandling.framework, but the delegate methods don't get called.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm out of ideas, then. I'd set a breakpoint on `NSLog` and see what code is logging the exception message -- the backtrace might tell you where the exception is getting caught.

Comment: I figured it out, I was setting the ExceptionHandling delegate in `+initialize` instead of `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. It's working now. Thanks!