# iOS Uncaught Exception Handler not getting called

Tags: ios, exception, handler

I have a similar situation to [Uncaught exception handler not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797922/uncaught-exception-handler-not-called) but his is a Mac application and mine is an iOS app. The solution was to use `ExceptionHandler` framework but that is not available on iOS.

I have a brand new iOS single view application and it is only a few lines of code so I won't paste my whole file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&handler);
    @throw NSInternalInconsistencyException;
    return YES;
}

void handler()                                                                              
{
    NSLog(@"hello world");                                                                  
}
```

So in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I set my custom exception handler and then force a crash. The exception handler is then meant to print `hello world` to the console but that does not happen. Putting break points in the handler shows that execution does not enter the method. However the exception gets printed to the console anyway (default action).

```
2014-07-24 08:58:25.476 Exception[430:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '__NSCFConstantString'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type __NSCFConstantString
```

Could there be another exception handler being set by default after my handler somewhere?

**UPDATE**

I decided to change how I force the crash from `NSInternalInconsistencyException` to `[[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"object"] objectAtIndex:1];`. The handler is now being called and `hello world` is being printed to the console.

So the question now is, why did `NSINternalInconsistencyException` not cause the handler to be called? The error is slightly different:

```
2014-07-24 10:13:51.333 Exception[1474:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
...
...
...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```